# Any reason why VBA filter didn't pick up certain conditions

Tags: vba, excel

Somehow VBA filter didn't pick up certain words included **Lockset**. it only gave me **Re-securing**. Why is this?

I also tried to delete the space in the array but it still didn't work. Is it about something that it only allows 256 characters?

```
ResultWorkbook.Worksheets(2).ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
    Array("Lockset replacement - Front or Main Entranceway - per door/door set          ", _
    "Lockset replacement - other than Front or Main ", _
    "Lockset replacement ? Front or Main Entranceway - per door/door set            ", _
    "Re-securing/re-keying of property"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit you question and add the relevant part of your code as text? It would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: What's with all of those spaces after your text in your Array? Are those spaces present exactly as-is in your spreadsheet?

Comment: I recorded the step of choosing these conditions. I didn't type in those conditions manually. Yes, it presented exactly as same as in the spreadsheet.

Comment: If you remove or comment out the third criterion (the one with the ? mark in it), does this cause the autofilter to return more results?

Comment: I didn't work after I removed the third criteria. I found an alternative way to get around which is use the wildcard

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use the wildcard in the criteria.

```
"=Lockset*"
```